# Multi-windows in Android 7.0 - Always get landscape layout even though device in multiwindows portrait mode

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing an android application that supports multi-windows feature on Android 7.0.
I followed [this guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window.html) on https://developer.android.com.
, imported sample project https://github.com/googlesamples/android-MultiWindowPlayground
I create a new resource named layout-land and did some testing. I recognized that landscape layout is inflated even though the device is in portrait mode.
Check out attached images.
[image]
[image]
How can I set portrait layout when device is in portrait mode.

Comment: Do you realize why Android takes landscape layout?

Comment: I am waiting for the answer

Comment: You did not answer my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume you have two screens. One is in landscape and one in portrait.
How can you say which one is in landscape and which one in portrait?

In portrait width of the screen is less than height.
And for landscape width of the screen is greater than height.

Agree?

So, here, when you enter multiwindow mode your app's window no longer fits screen - width is greater than height and it is considered as landscape.
That is why landscape layout resource is used.

There is no separate modifier for layout resource to be used in split-screen mode.

The only thing you can do to achieve portrait in your case is to remove layout-land.

Or you can create two separate layouts (without any modifiers such as `-land`) and in activity call `activity.isInMultiWindowMode();` to choose corresponding layout you want to use.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When app run in multiwindows mode, the layout gets device's width for layout height and device's height for the layout width. <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >   Do you have any suggestion for this situation ?